# Do I need to get a license for a ecommerce page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, e-commerce

On my Drupal website I will have one page that requires a user to purchase something via form.  My question is do I need to apply for  some kind license (SSL License)?
If it is only one form do I need to look into the Drupal Commerce module or can I just handle with webforms?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are processing credit card info you need an SSL certificate. If you are using a third party service for payment processing (i.e. Paypal) then you don't.

See this page: [Do I Need An SSL Certificate For My Website?](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-do-i-need-an-ssl-certificate-for-my-website.html)

2) You could implement with or without Drupal Commerce - but using a module such as Drupal Commerce would make it easier to extend functionality if needed in the future, and would require less coding to get it up and running initially.